# C# | The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process, even after closing Binary writer and reader

Tags: c#, binary

I started learning C# about, 3 days ago, and I had some knowledge of Java before.

I've been working on a program in these 3 days, mostly so I could get the hang of C#, and so I can learn, and all that.

In this program, it's simply to change a few bytes in a file, but that's not the point of this. The point is, I got all of that to work, and loading the bytes and writing the bytes to the file works perfectly, except when.. after I close the program after changing the bytes, and I open it again, I can load them, but then when I try to save, I get this error. The process cannot access the file '(the file)' because it is being used by another process.

I am absolutely positive that it's not being used for something else, because the only things I have opened are Opera, Visual Studio, and the program, which is being debugged. If it helps, here are the important parts (I know, the code sucks, but I'm new..):

Reading/Displaying:

```
choose = Names.Items.IndexOf(Names.SelectedItem);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose), SeekOrigin.Begin);
HPtb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose) + 1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Attb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose) + 2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Deftb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose) + 3, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Sptb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose) + 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
SpAtb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose) + 5, SeekOrigin.Begin);
SpDtb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
br.Close();
```

Writing:

```
Names.Items.IndexOf(Names.SelectedItem);
BinaryWriter black = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName));
black.BaseStream.Position = BaseStats + (choose  * 0x1C);
String[] statbox = new String[] { HPtb.Text, Attb.Text, Deftb.Text, Sptb.Text, SpAtb.Text, SpDtb.Text };
foreach (String element in statbox)
{
    black.Write((byte)int.Parse(element));
}
black.Close();
```

The exact line which I get the error is:

```
BinaryWriter black = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName));
```

Edit: The whole program: http://pastebin.com/MaVULd5q (had to separate it to be able to post)

Lines related to this  are: 119, 132, 148, and 156

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. ive edited your question.avoid being too chatty and using words like thanks in advance , as they are not appropriate here. [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: put your complete code, the part related to reading the file, it will let us to help you more

Comment: We don't like questions about pieces of pastebin code. Trim it down to something you can post as part of the question.

Comment: loadROMToolStripMenuItem_Click does not close the binary reader or the stream it is given. Please go through all file-related objects, figure out which ones are `IDisposable` and ensure **all of them** are disposed. Yes, this means stuffing the file you get from `File.OpenRead` into its own variable and disposing it separately from the `BinaryReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out using statements for file access.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path)) 
{
    var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    br.BaseStream.Seek(BaseStats + (28 * choose), SeekOrigin.Begin);
    HPtb.Text = br.ReadBytes(1)[0].ToString();
    br.Close();
}
```

You'll want that file stream to get disposed. This is a clear, easy way to help ensure that.